# Gutenberg add checkbox using PluginPostStatusInfo

Tags: block-editor

In an attempt to replace the fucntionality of `post_submitbox_misc_actions` using gutenberg, I have the below.....

```
import { registerPlugin } from '@wordpress/plugins';
import { PluginPostStatusInfo } from '@wordpress/edit-post';
import { CheckboxControl } from '@wordpress/components';
 
const PluginPostStatusInfoTest = () => (
    <PluginPostStatusInfo>
        <p>Post Status Info SlotFill</p>
    </PluginPostStatusInfo>
);
 
registerPlugin( 'post-status-info-test', { render: PluginPostStatusInfoTest } );
```

This is working well and is adding `PostStatus Info SlotFill` text to the correct place in the sidebar. But not I am trying to add a checkbox in that can be saved with the post.

Does anybody have an example they can show me? Can I just add a HTML checkbox or do I need to do it in a more WP native way?

Do I need to do anything different with regards to saving or can I just use the `save_post` action like with the classic editor?

Answer (score 1):

I happen to be working on the same thing this weekend. Here is [the relevant documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/components/checkbox-control/) that has most of what you need to get up and running. I'm using a ToggleControl but it is very similar to using a CheckboxControl. I'll paste code below but you will also find [this extensive tutorial](https://css-tricks.com/managing-wordpress-metadata-in-gutenberg-using-a-sidebar-plugin/) to be very helpful.

**Define your toggle:**

```
//Gutenburg toggle
let GutenbergToggle = (props) => {
    return (
        <ToggleControl
        label="Some Toggle Control"
        checked={ props.state }
        onChange={(value) => props.onBlockEditorToggleChange(value)}
        />
    )
}
```

**Then add it to the panel:**

```
const PluginPostStatusInfoTest = () => (
    <PluginPostStatusInfo>
        <p>Post Status Info SlotFill</p>
        <GutenbergToggle />
    </PluginPostStatusInfo>
);
```

Rudimentary code to save and retrieve the data:

```
GutenbergToggle = withSelect(
    (select) => {
        return {
            state: select('core/editor').getEditedPostAttribute('meta')['_use_block_editor']
        }
    }
)(GutenbergToggle);

GutenbergToggle = withDispatch(
    (dispatch) => {
        return {
            onBlockEditorToggleChange: (value) => {
                dispatch('core/editor').editPost({ meta: { _use_block_editor: value } });
            }
        }
    }
)(GutenbergToggle);
```